# kotlin shorthand version for if(true)

Tags: kotlin

In Javascript you can write

```
if (condition){
  console.log("")
}
```

as

```
condition && console.log("")
```

is there a similar syntax in koltin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike Javascript, kotlin is strictly typed. Both side of the `&&` operator must be a `Boolean`. You can do some meaningless equality check to achieve this, but it just makes things less readable. For examples:

```
condition && (println("Hello, world!") == Unit)
```

or

```
condition && (println("Hello, world!") == null)
```

Even ternary operator (`c?a:b`) is removed in kotlin and they suggest using `if(c) a else b`. So just stick with the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <T>Boolean.ifTrue(supplier: () -> T) = if (this) supplier() else null
```

Then just is it like

```
someExpression.ifTrue{doSomething()}
```

or

```
val myValue = someExpression.ifTrue{doSomething()} ?: someDefault
```

Comment: to improve the answer, could please add some narrative or explanation as to how the code works

Comment: See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6938/BooleanifTrue